# use this keyword for main function of class/upper function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to figure out a how to use variables that I declared in a JavaScript class. but since I'm using a function inside of it the this keyword now uses that, so what I'm asking is how do I use the variables declared throughout the class inside of a new function.

Example:

```
function SomeClass(){
    this.classVariable = 1;
    this.classVariable2 = 2;
}

SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    return function(){
           // do stuff with class variables in here
           return this.classVariable + this.classVariable2;
    }
}
```

I know that you could have done return this.classVariable + this.classVariable2 but, that was an example for my question.

So how would I retrieve class variables from within another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common solution is to define a `that` variable like so:

```
SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
  var that = this;
  return function(){
    // do stuff with class variables in here
    return that.classVariable + that.classVariable2;
  }
}
```

Another solution would be to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
  var fun = function() {
    // do stuff with class variables in here
    return this.classVariable + this.classVariable2;
  }
  return fun.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`bind` the returned function to `this` so that the function doesn't lose its context:

```
SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    return function(){
        // do stuff with class variables in here
        return this.classVariable + this.classVariable2;
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the that=this idiom. Define a variable (often named "that", but it doesn't matter) in the member function that points to `this` and the closure will be able to access the object through that reference.